# Why does my Indian food taste bland?

Tags: indian-cuisine

I recently tried an Indian [recipe](https://www.halfbakedharvest.com/easy-healthier-crockpot-butter-chicken/) and event though it was spicy hot, it didn't have much flavor which surprised me for how much seasoning I put in. Does anyone know why this might be so bland?

> - 1 pound boneless skinless chicken breast cut into bite size chunks
> - 1/2 onion finely minced
> - 2 tablespoons butter
> - 3 cloves garlic minced or grated
> - 1 tablespoon freshly grated ginger
> - 2 teaspoons curry powder
> - 1-2 teaspoons Thai red curry paste
> - 2 tablespoons garam masala
> - 1/2-1 teaspoon turmeric
> - 1 teaspoon cayenne pepper, use less if you are not a spicy person
> - 1/4 teaspoon salt
> - 1 (6 ounce) can tomato paste
> - 1 (14 ounce) can coconut milk
> - 1/2 cup greek yogurt
> - 1/4 cup half and half or heavy cream
> - cooked white rice for serving
> - Fresh homemade naan for scooping (a must!)

> In a large glass measuring cup or bowl mix together the coconut milk, greek yogurt and cream. Stir in the tomato paste, garlic, ginger and all the spices. Mix well.
>
> Spray the inside of your crockpot bowl with cooking spray or grease with olive oil. To the bowl sprinkle the onion over the bottom. Add the chicken and then pour the coconut milk mixture over the chicken so the chicken is completely covered. Add the butter and place the lid on the crockpot. Cook on high for 4 hours or on low for 6 to 8 hours.

Comment: Have you taken a test for a certain widespread disease that commonly affects the sense of smell (which is most of the sense of taste) recently....perhaps you should. Stale spices can also be an issue.

Comment: @Ecnerwal COVID-19 isn't Voldemort lol. It's okay to say it

Comment: There was a similar question, recently [Why does my curry taste flat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/121069/why-does-my-curry-taste-flat)

Comment: @Ecnerwal lol, no I do not have it (90% sure), but I was momentarily concerned.

Comment: @Ivo Though Voldemort doesn't have a nose and hence may suffer from lack of taste ...

Comment: I've copied the recipe over, to save people having to scroll past 432 nearly identical pictures of what a curry looks like.

Comment: I'd second the points that simply say that this is avoiding most of the techniques that go into making traditional curries taste good. I'd guess it was missing fenugreek and some other aromatics. Fry the spices, which will help. Fry the onions, ginger, garlic and curry paste (can be done together). Fry the tomato paste. I'd have a look at Vivek Singh's recipe for it too - https://www.viveksingh.co.uk/march-old-delhi-style-butter-chicken/ - don't have to make it exactly like this, but he's pretty good on techniques (though his recipes can be tough)

Comment: I had to google for "1 pound in kg". Couldn't the world just use the metric system?

Comment: @Nav I'm American, and I wholeheartedly agree with you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The recipe provided doesn't provide enough salt.

Taking just the pound of chicken breast (454 g) and 1/4 tsp salt (~1.5 g) you have a salt content of approx. 0.3%; but, factor in:

- 1/2 onion (85 g, medium)
- 3 cloves garlic (12 g, small)
- 6 ounce can tomato paste (~170 g)
- 14 ounce can coconut milk (~340 g)
- 1/2 cup greek yogurt (~140 g)
- 1/4 cup half and half or heavy cream (~120 g)

...and you have an additional ~870 g of food for approximately 1,320 g total, diluting the added salt content to ~0.1% without accounting for salted/unsalted butter.

Try adding a bit of salt, a small pinch at a time, stirring thoroughly to mix and tasting after each addition. Even better, use a liquid source of sodium with other flavour compounds - soy sauce, fish sauce, Maggi seasoning, etc. instead of salt.

From [*Strategies to Reduce Sodium Intake in the United States - SALT FLAVOR EFFECTS*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK50958/#ch3.s7):

> *Salt imparts more than just a salt taste to overall food flavor. In work with a variety of foods (soups, rice, eggs, and potato chips), salt was found to improve the perception of product thickness, enhance sweetness, mask metallic or chemical off-notes, and round out overall flavor while improving flavor intensity (Gillette, 1985). These effects are illustrated in Figure 3-2, using soup as an example. In the figure, the distance of each of the points (e.g., “thickness,” “saltiness”) from the center point represents the intensity of that particular attribute. This figure shows that when salt is added to a soup, not only does it increase the saltiness of that soup (compare closed circles with open triangles and open circles for saltiness), but it also increases other positive attributes, such as thickness, fullness, and overall balance.*

[image: Fig. 3-2 from Gillette, 1985]

*Figure 3-2 referenced - Gillette M. Flavor effects of sodium chloride. Food Technology. 1985;39(6):47–52.*

Comment: Sure, there's not enough salt - but that's not nearly the half of it. It's a truly *terrible* recipe, with zero method. It's going to be under-salt, over-perfumed, almost soup consistency with chicken like bullets.

Comment: Yes, the recipe is suboptimal - that I agree with wholeheartedly. Given that @Brandon Kauffman already made it and only complained about blandness, correcting the salt content would be the first and easiest step in salvaging any leftovers.

Comment: Adding on to that, he could also properly fry an additional batch of alliums and toast spices, as you described for proper technique, to add in to the current batch if the flavour is still weak.

Comment: A tarka might give it a bit of a refresh, yeah, but it's going to take a lot to mask all that garam masala & the bitter depths of the tomato paste.

Comment: Also depends a lot on what kind of salt you use.  So called "kosher salt" is much less salty in flavor than your typical table salt, so you need to use more of it to compensate  (this also allows you to be more nuanced with it).  I've seen high level chefs make this mistake because they often use kosher salt exclusively in their profession, so when working in a non-professional kitchen with regular salt, they tend to over-salt because they're so used to the less-salty salt.

Comment: AFAIK kosher salt is just less salty because it has more air in it. It's the same saltiness by weight, but less salty by volume.

Comment: @unlisted How do you come to that conclusion? Not attacking, genuinely curious; teach me  lol.

Comment: @Daevin - making a decent facsimile of a BIR curry was something that eluded me for 20 years, no matter what I tried [this was not helped at all by a move from the North of England to London, where very few BIR curries are anywhere near as good as where I grew up]. By the time I finally got it, it all just fell into place. Have a look at the link in my answer below - that boils down a lot of technique into an easy to follow structure.

Comment: @bdsl May be the case, but given the recipe has everything measured by volume (teaspoons, tablespoons, cups) and not by weight (grams, or more likely ounces since it's using Imperial units), this is still a possible source of error.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - there's enough slack in a curry recipe to not get over-worried about teaspoons vs grammes precision, so long as the ingredients are in the ball-park & there's some method involved. Two tablespoons of garam masala, though, is bordering on a crime against humanity.

Answer (score 28):

You just don't make a curry by throwing all the ingredients in a pan & heating them for a while.
Even using good ingredients & putting enough salt in, that recipe will come out bland. I'd also imagine it would be a little bitter too  because of the tomato paste thrown in 'raw' & the amount of garam masala is complete overkill.

Curry is *all about method* as well as ingredients. Two different people given the same ingredients will make two different curries, on method alone.

The onions, garlic & ginger should be fried, the spices should be fried, the tomato paste should be fried [if you don't, it will be bitter]. The coconut milk & cream should go in near the end, so should the garam massala.
The butter should be ghee - different flavour profile.

See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/121074/42066 for more detail on general curry methods.

It's honestly just a lazy recipe - as comments indicate, it's a clickbait recipe. It doesn't belong on anyone's list of 'how to make curry', of any sort.

The more I look at even the ingredients list, the more I worry about it. It's a truly terrible recipe.
Even if we're using generic supermarket curry powder, there's nowhere near enough. There's also *far* too much garam masala [possibly to try cover for the fact it's going to be cooked into submission rather than added late so you can taste it].
There's not enough onion to make the sauce properly, so it's making up 'gravy' with a lot of additional liquid ingredients. I've never known quite so much 'wet' in what purports to be an "Indian" curry - coconut, cream *and* yoghurt. Maybe one of those, not all three.
…and cooking skinless chicken breast for 4 hours is going to come out like bullets.

So… under-salt, under 'curried', over-perfumed, consistency of soup & inedible chicken… what's not to like? ;)

If you read the comments under the online recipe, then once you get past the 'paid to give it 5 stars' reviews, you find complaints about each of these points.

Comment: +1 The recipe is terrible, it looks like a standard SEO clickbait recipe that was written (or generated) first and foremost so that it would float near the top of google search results. I wouldn't bother trying to fix it. The most significant problem is the big lack of salt borkymcfood's answer gives (I'd start with 1 tsp for the volume of ingredients given). Another big one is cooking boneless skinless chicken breast for *4 hours*. Just find a better recipe.

Comment: @DanC - yup, I just added another para about the abysmal balance between ingredients. I've never ever tried slow-cooking chicken breast so idk how much like pencil erasers it's going to be after that kind of time, but yup, you'd just drop it less than 10 mins before serving, so it's still actually chewable ;) [The comments underneath the recipe are funny too, apart from the 'friends glowing reviews', the rest mention watery, tough chicken, way too much garam masala...

Comment: I'm a little confused by the commentary here. Does the ingredient selection somehow help with SEO? Or are we only suggesting that a junk recipe was filled into a heavily SEO-optimized template without heed to quality?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - You'd need an expert on SEO, not a cook. If you read the page, it's typical of this style of 'cooking' clickbait. It's mostly pictures & descriptions of how easy it is, how much it invokes feelings of well-being, how 'healthy' it is… rather than getting on with the food. It is also, when you do finally reach it, is a truly terrible recipe, with a method that will produce, as the OP discovered, flavourless pencil erasers.

Comment: A recipe designed by someone who ought not to do this for a living & one that we could hope would fall to the bottom of any search engine's list, never to be found again by unsuspecting beginner cooks who don't yet *know* how to read a recipe to know whether it will be good or not, without actually making it.

Answer (score 13):

I think the "Healthy" recipe title says it all here - although with the butter and cream  components I think the author was stretching that point somewhat!

Seriously though, many healthy recipes are just reworked "Unhealthy" ones with reduced salt, sugar or fat content. These three ingredients are why so much processed food tastes so good, and why our taste buds crave for more.

As you have discovered, even a heavily spiced dish can taste bland if there is not enough salt or umami flavouring.

In the case of your Butter Chicken recipe, first of all I'd ensure the spices you use are fresh, and clearly have an aroma. Stale spices won't taste of much.

Secondly, a good dish is a balanced dish. Each flavour should compliment or contrast its neighbour. That is why chilli and chocolate go together. In the BC dish, there is a lot of richness to cut through, the danger here being that the dish ends up too rich or "Sickly". I'd be tempted to add some lemon juice or dry white wine at the end to cut through all the fat and cream. Another possibility would be to increase the amount of yoghurt and decrease the cream content etc.

Finally, the biggest issue with this dish. It is barely seasoned, and that explains why most professional recipes add "Or to taste" to salt measurements etc. It is a tricky one though, some people are more/less salt tolerant than others. The best guidance recommends tasting everything for seasoning before serving, and adjusting accordingly. If you must stick to such low salt levels (e.g. for health reasons), you could try increasing the salt level a bit but using a low sodium salt instead. Alternatively, you could add some MSG (monosodium glutamate), but I don't know what health implications this would have for someone on a low sodium diet, negative I presume.

Comment: The answer seems to suggest it's impossible to make a good-tasting and healthy version of the dish. I question whether that is the case. Although of course *healthy* is subjective.

Comment: I've always been led to believe that a good BC is deliberately decadent, and not a dish for everyday consumption due to the sheer amount of calories etc. I'm sure there are healthy variations out there, but they will always be a compromise of calories and ingredients versus taste, which is just as subjective.

Comment: @MichaelMior There's plenty of delicious healthy meals one can make but you can't just take the "unhealthy" bits out of dish and expect it to work.